# Filter excel data based on column value powershell

Tags: powershell

I am having a excel with around 34k data like below

```
SYMM_ID     DATE                    INSTANCE                Total Response Time
297900076   2022-10-23 11:25:00 PM  GS_GTS_ORACLUL_L_PRDPRF 0.21
297900076   2022-10-24 02:15:00 AM  GS_GTS_ORACLUL_L_PRDPRF 0.36
297900076   2022-10-24 04:20:00 AM  GS_GTS_ORACLUL_L_PRDPRF 0.96
297900076   2022-10-24 04:25:00 AM  GS_GTS_ORACLUL_L_PRDPRF 0.3
297900076   2022-10-24 04:30:00 AM  GS_GTS_ORACLUL_L_PRDPRF 1.21
297900076   2022-10-24 04:35:00 AM  GS_GTS_ORACLUL_L_PRDPRF 0.48
297900076   2022-10-24 04:40:00 AM  GS_GTS_ORACLUL_L_PRDPRF 1.17
297900076   2022-10-24 04:45:00 AM  GS_GTS_ORACLUL_L_PRDPRF 0.33
297900076   2022-10-24 04:50:00 AM  GS_GTS_ORACLUL_L_PRDPRF 0.57
297900076   2022-10-24 04:55:00 AM  GS_GTS_ORACLUL_L_PRDPRF 0.34
297900076   2022-10-23 05:00:00 AM  GS_GTS_ORACLUL_L_PRDSTD 0.35
297900076   2022-10-23 05:05:00 AM  GS_GTS_ORACLUL_L_PRDSTD 1.02
297900076   2022-10-23 05:10:00 AM  GS_GTS_ORACLUL_L_PRDSTD 0.68
297900076   2022-10-23 05:15:00 AM  GS_GTS_ORACLUL_L_PRDSTD 0.72
297900076   2022-10-23 05:20:00 AM  GS_GTS_ORACLUL_L_PRDSTD 0.67
297900076   2022-10-23 05:25:00 AM  GS_GTS_ORACLUL_L_PRDSTD 0.57
297900076   2022-10-23 05:30:00 AM  GS_GTS_ORACLUL_L_PRDSTD 0.64
297900076   2022-10-23 05:35:00 AM  GS_GTS_ORACLUL_L_PRDSTD 0.61
297900076   2022-10-23 05:40:00 AM  GS_GTS_ORACLUL_L_PRDSTD 0.56
297900076   2022-10-23 05:45:00 AM  GS_GTS_ORACLUL_L_PRDSTD 0.57
297900076   2022-10-23 05:50:00 AM  GS_GTS_ORACLUL_L_PRDSTD 0.5
297900076   2022-10-23 05:55:00 AM  GS_GTS_ORACLUL_L_PRDSTD 0.66
297900076   2022-10-23 06:00:00 AM  GS_GTS_ORACLUL_L_PRDSTD 0.63
297900076   2022-10-23 06:05:00 AM  GS_GTS_ORACLUL_L_PRDSTD 1.1
297900076   2022-10-23 11:00:00 PM  GS_GTS_LOCCLUL_L_PRDPRF 0.36
297900076   2022-10-23 11:05:00 PM  GS_GTS_LOCCLUL_L_PRDPRF 0.84
297900076   2022-10-23 11:10:00 PM  GS_GTS_LOCCLUL_L_PRDPRF 0.93
297900076   2022-10-23 11:15:00 PM  GS_GTS_LOCCLUL_L_PRDPRF 0.55
297900076   2022-10-23 11:20:00 PM  GS_GTS_LOCCLUL_L_PRDPRF 0.53
297900076   2022-10-23 11:25:00 PM  GS_GTS_LOCCLUL_L_PRDPRF 0.48
297900076   2022-10-23 11:30:00 PM  GS_GTS_LOCCLUL_L_PRDPRF 0.58
297900076   2022-10-23 11:35:00 PM  GS_GTS_LOCCLUL_L_PRDPRF 0.67
297900076   2022-10-23 11:40:00 PM  GS_GTS_LOCCLUL_L_PRDPRF 0.38
297900076   2022-10-23 11:45:00 PM  GS_GTS_LOCCLUL_L_PRDPRF 0.74
297900076   2022-10-23 11:50:00 PM  GS_GTS_LOCCLUL_L_PRDPRF 0.51
297900076   2022-10-23 11:55:00 PM  GS_GTS_LOCCLUL_L_PRDPRF 0.56
297900076   2022-10-24 12:00:00 AM  GS_GTS_LOCCLUL_L_PRDPRF 0.45
297900076   2022-10-24 12:05:00 AM  GS_GTS_LOCCLUL_L_PRDPRF 1.88
297900076   2022-10-24 12:10:00 AM  GS_GTS_LOCCLUL_L_PRDPRF 0.75
297900076   2022-10-24 12:15:00 AM  GS_GTS_LOCCLUL_L_PRDPRF 0.6
297900076   2022-10-24 12:20:00 AM  GS_GTS_LOCCLUL_L_PRDPRF 0.63
297900076   2022-10-24 12:25:00 AM  GS_GTS_LOCCLUL_L_PRDPRF 0.96
297900076   2022-10-24 12:30:00 AM  GS_GTS_LOCCLUL_L_PRDPRF 0.58
297900076   2022-10-24 12:35:00 AM  GS_GTS_LOCCLUL_L_PRDPRF 0.64
297900076   2022-10-24 12:40:00 AM  GS_GTS_LOCCLUL_L_PRDPRF 0.73
297900076   2022-10-24 12:45:00 AM  GS_GTS_LOCCLUL_L_PRDPRF 0.54
297900076   2022-10-24 12:50:00 AM  GS_GTS_LOCCLUL_L_PRDPRF 0.57
```

I am using below code to get the total number of rows from the sheet

```
$workbook = $excel.workbooks.open('C:\SLAFile.xlsx')
$worksheet = $workbook.Worksheets.Item(1)
$rows = $worksheet.range("D2").currentregion.rows.count
```

But I have to filter the data and get the row count of rows having **"PRF"** and **"STD"** in `INSTANCE`.

I have to execute different formulas based on `INSTANCE`(for PRF different and for STD different formula)

Please let me know how to filter the column data and get the row counts

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be better of using the [ImportExcel](https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel) module. That would make an object in PowerShell we can easily work with.

There are a few ways you can do this given the amount of rows, but the simplest one would be with `Where-Object`

```
import-module ImportExcel

$eFile=Import-Excel 'C:\Working\temp\test.xlsx'
$PRF=$eFile.'INSTANCE               ' | Where-Object {$_ -like '*PRF'}
$STD=$eFile.'INSTANCE               ' | Where-Object {$_ -like '*STD'}

Write-Host "*PRF - $($PRF.count)"
Write-Host "*STD - $($STD.count)"
```